# Pushing Branches in Github - Local Branch?

Tags: git, github, branch

I have a branch on my computer named "Test_data_we". However, this branch doesn't appear on the GitHub account. When I push it using GitHub, it automatically merges this branch with one that is visible on the GitHub page, titled "Test_data_cc". Why doesn't "Test_data_we" appear as it's own branch on GitHub once I push it?

Comment: What is the output of `git branch -va`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute below command

```
git push origin Test_data_we
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your branch empty? Or it has commits? If your branch isn't visible on githb i.e. remote that means you haven't pushed it even once.
You need to execute command

```
git push origin branch_name_to_be_pushed
git push origin Test_data_we
```

After this while creating a pull request you need to check the source and destination branch. Git never merges branch automatically.